# GN Netcom 4800 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I have an old GN 4800 Headset that I have used on Windows XP (up to 2005) and on
Linux out of the box; No driver installation was necessary.
But now I have to use Win 10 and it would not work. Sometimes it claims that
is not connected even if it is plugged in (Code 45) and sometimes it shows
Device could not be started (Code 10)
I have searched on the Internet for a driver but whatever I have downloaded
is not working for that device (USB ID 0b0e:4800 GN Netcom)

Another solution I have tried was a jackd server on a Raspberry Pi (3B) and a
jackd/asiobridge setup on win 10. This is working but the network Trafik is so
high that there is an impact on other apps running on the win 10 machine.

Is it possible to reactivate this headset with the information from the win XP
installation? (the old Windows XP installation is still existing in a virtual
environment and it is working with the headset in a VM)

Is it possible to connect the hardware to a VM **AND** forwarding the audio in/out
to the host audio system so that the audio sound of the host is redirected to
the VM and from there to the hardware?

Is there another solution maybe with a sound server on a raspberry pi or drivers on a WSL 2 subsystem?

Answer (score 1):

If drivers for this headset do not exist for Windows 10, then there is not any way you can make it work in Windows 10.

You have already explored the virtual machine ways.

At this point, you probably need to replace the headset with a Windows 10 compatible device. There are decent inexpensive headsets available in the marketplace.

Comment: the GN 4800 is not only a simple headset; It is a headset with connetions to usb and a telephone and including a ring sensor with automatic switch from computer output to telephone output; Even here in Germany this is not inexpensive headset starting at 150 Eur (180 USD).
And another thing; It has worked on Windows XP "out-of-the-box" without any drivers so why must I have a driver for Windosw 10?

Comment: It was designed some time back (in the time of XP).  That is why it apparently needs drivers now, because Windows 10 is so vastly different.